# how can I delete file which has invalid file name?

Tags: windows, admin, filenames, delete-file

[image]

There is 2 loader.bin.
But one of them has carrage return at the end of the file name.
Because of this, I can't delete the file, and directory containing the file.
Even with command prompt, I can't delete it.
I tried:

```
del *
del loader.*
```

above says name or label is wrong.
So I

```
cd ..
dir /x
```

to check DOS path name of the directory
And delete with DOS path
del TEXT_L~1
and again, above says name or label is wrong.

I also tried to delete the directory with "\?\" prefix.
something like:

```
del "\\?\D:\directory\blahblah\directory"
```

and again, name error occurs.

How can I delete this file?
Can I have some hint?

I guess that there is carriage return at the end of name because auto complete in git bash complete the name as "loader.bin^M"

I think the file came from wrong command from batch file like:

```
fasm file.asm loader.bin(here's carriage return)
```

(fasm is assembler program)
Batch file's end of line may have been changed while I changed platform from linux to windows.

EDIT:
The file refused to get deleted with following method too.

1. delete with /P option

   ```
   del /P directoryName
   ```
2. with DeleteFileW windows API

   ```
   #include <windows.h>
   int main()
   {
       DeleteFileW(L"E:\\directory\\blahblah\\directory");
   }
   ```

Comment: The ``\\?\`` prefix can only bypass limits imposed by DOS compatibility. In this case, the issue is instead that NT filesystems disallow control characters (ordinals 1-31) in filenames, so there's no way to open a handle to the file to rename or delete it. Maybe there's a low-level approach using a filesystem IOCTL.

Comment: In Windows 10 I can create and delete a file with the name `"loader.bin\r"` in a Virtualbox shared folder that's hosted in Linux. It doesn't even require the ``\\?\`` prefix. This shows that success here depends on the filesystem or filesystem-redirector driver. Microsoft's filesystem drivers (e.g. NTFS) don't allow it, so probably your drive D: is a locally mounted filesystem, probably using a Microsoft driver. But it would help if you can provide the exact details.

Comment: @eryksun the file system is NTFS. I think I need to make little program that delete the file or use ubuntu live usb. Thanks. I wonder if you can give me some hint on what API should I use to delete this file? Thanks

Comment: if use `ZwDeleteFile` you can delete any file name(of course if it not in use, and you have permission)

Comment: @RbMm, if the filename has a control character in it, `NtDeleteFile` for an NTFS volume fails with the status value `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID`. While this system call is quicker than a normal delete-on-close operation (i.e. it doesn't require invoking the object manager to create a real `File` object), it still uses the normal path parsing to open the file (starting at `ObOpenObjectByName`), which ultimately depends on the filesystem driver to process an `IRP_MJ_CREATE` request. Microsoft's NTFS driver will fail this request; it stops parsing a path as soon as it sees an invalid character.

Comment: `DeleteFileW` won't work in this case for NTFS, even if used properly (i.e. deleting a file, not a directory). That's the normal route that calls `NtOpenFile` to get a File handle and then `NtSetInformationFile` to set the delete disposition on the filesystem's underlying file/link control block. It will fail at `NtOpenFile`. I don't know a  direct way to delete a filename like this. I was only speculating that the NTFS driver may support some back-door IOCTL (i.e. via `DeviceIoControl`) to allow deleting or renaming a file with an invalid name. I just use Linux for this problem.

Comment: @eryksun - but how this file was created ? if it created with `NtCreateFile` (or shell over it) - it can be and deleted. may be name containing another characters - need call `ZwQueryDirectoryFile` for view names exactly as is and delete every file

Comment: @RbMm, you can't create a file with a control character in its name on an NTFS volume mounted in Windows. `NtCreateFile` will fail because the filesystem driver fails the `IRP_MJ_CREATE` request. The NTFS driver only allows control characters in named streams, e.g. `"loader.bin:stream\r"`. I can only assume that the file was created in Linux (as I did when testing this) -- but not in the Windows 10 Linux subsystem, which will fail the `open` system call with `ENOENT` because ultimately it depends on the same NTFS driver.

Comment: @eryksun - because topic marked with *windows* keyword - i assume that file created inside windows. and if file created with some name - it can be and opened and deleted. if it created not under windows, and later disk mounted in windows - this is another question. so need delete file in os where he is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem never happened to me but maybe using `del /P directory` you could be able to remove the file.

[image: Example]

## Update

You could use a live Linux distro and delete the file you need.

Thanks

Comment: It says: do you really want to delete file loader.bin? and I type "Y". Same name error occurs. Do I need to format this drive? or installing linux and delete from there may help?

Comment: Hi, I would say that format would be too much and install Linux maybe not necessary. Could you use a live distro, mount the filesystem and try removing the file?

Comment: I installed ubuntu linux and now I am able to delete the file. Thanks. Please update the answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to help any future lost folks who landed on this same page, this is what finally did it for me:

```
del "\\?\D:\IceDrive\Multimedia\Pictures\Events_Trips_and_Occasions\2022\2022 09 23 Bill Joel Concert "
```

Notice the space at the end.  I could not delete that folder via any other means and it was messing up my Windows IceDrive sync.